# applying paddingRight to flex grid column not to grid header

Tags: apache-flex, flex-mx

Whenever I add paddingRight to a column in the flex grid, it adds the padding to the header as well.
Is anyone familiar with how I can add paddingRight just to the column and not to the header? Below is the column code where I was specifying the padding.

```
<mx:DataGridColumn width="60" headerText="Type" dataField="Grade" headerStyleName="headerLeft" textAlign="left"  draggable="false" resizable="false" headerRenderer="GridHeaderRenderer" paddingRight="5"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the paddingRight on the column, then for the header, override the header's paddingRight in the headerStyleName. (note this won't work for paddingTop or paddingBottom)

Comment: you are correct. The headerstyle will completely override what is specified in the grid.